# React-native : Unable to use react-native-fast-image

Tags: android, react-native

My apps app/build gradle:

> ```
> android:compileSdkVersion 23,  buildToolsVersion '26'
> ```

android/build gradle:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25
                buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

package json dependencies:

> "react-native-fast-image": "^1.0.0",
>    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
>   "react-native": "0.45.1",

I have installed react-native-fast-image, and linked with react-native.
Then while running on android , I am getting this error:

```
:react-native-fast-image:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
D:\React Practice\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\src\main\java\com\dylanvann\fastimage\FastImageViewPackage.java:14: error: FastImageViewPackage is not abstract and does not override abstract method createJSModules() in ReactPackage
public class FastImageViewPackage implements ReactPackage {
       ^
Note: D:\React Practice\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\react-native-fast-image\android\src\main\java\com\dylanvann\fastimage\FastImageViewManager.java uses unchecked or un
safe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
:react-native-fast-image:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Comment: i don't know about this bug, but when i tried to use react-native-fast-image i run into this issue: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/238 which is not fixed yet, and it has been open for some time now. Basically it only worked in IOS not android.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is already fixed on the last version of [react-native-fast-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image).

Or you can fix it manually my editing `node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android/src/main/java/com/dylanvann/fastimage/FastImageViewPackage.java` and add:

```
@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Also, if you have upgrade your `react-native` to a version greater than 0.47.0 (in your example you are using 0.45.1), you need to remove the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

you can update JDK 11.0.11

brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11

choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11